# How do I ensure assets are present with Rail 7, cssbundling-rails, jsbundling-rails in test mode (RSpec)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, yarnpkg, esbuild

I'm upgrading a large, commercial (proprietary) Rails 6 application to Rails 7. We never used Webpacker, and are instead going directly from bundled gems for things like Bootstrap, to the "Rails 7 way".

It turns out that the "no Node" workflow for Rails 7 has no good answer for components that consist of both a CSS and JS component. In our case, the most obvious offender there is Bootstrap. Faced with maintaining the JS "half" of Bootstrap through import maps and the CSS "half" through something like the old Bootstrap gem or manual vendoring (and yes, there [really is no other solution without Node here](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/issues/107)) we end up back at a full Node workflow.

This is coming together. All front-end components that provide CSS and/or JS were already happily available in NPM, so now that's all managed via `package.json` & Yarn, with `bin/dev` driving Sass & `esbuild` compilation of the SCSS and JS components pulled from either `app/assets`, `app/javascript` or `node_modules/...`; the asset pipeline `manifest.js` contains only references to the `build` and `images` folders inside `app/assets` as a result.

It feels like a bit of backwards step with all the heavyweight manual maintenance of lists of filenames (wildcard imports no longer supported) along with the complexity of the multiple processes now running under Foreman vs just having things synchronously processed in Sprockets on a per-request basis, but with all that stuff being deprecated/abandonware, it was clearly time to update.

This all works fine in dev & production mode, but what about test? We use RSpec; in CI, there's no built assets and developers don't want to have to remember to run `esbuild`  or `assets:precompile` or whatever every time they're about to run `rspec`. Apart from anything else, it's quite slow.

What's the official, idiomatic Rails 7 solution in a Yarn/Node-based workflow specifically using `cssbundling-rails` and `jsbundling-rails`, **when you want to run tests with up to date assets?**

Comment: "What's the official, idiomatic Rails 7 solution in a Yarn/Node-based workflow" - there won't be one. Rails 7 is really more a you do your own thing approach compared to sprockets or webpacker.

Comment: The question got edited and the well-meaning editor unfortunately removed vital information - specifically with cssbundling-rails and jsbundling-rails. Edited question & added that back. To be clear, in previous versions of Rails we just go `bundle exec rspec` and all assets are up to date when tests run. This doesn't work with Rails 7 + those gems.

Comment: I feel your pain. Spockets was a convenient solution but unfortunately flawed in so many ways that it wasn't a viable option for the future. Not completely sue how to solve it but can't you automate the esbuild steps on the CI? Guard can be used locally to run processes when the files are changed.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty ropey but better than nothing for now; it'll ensure CI always builds assets and also ensure that local development always has up-to-date assets, even if things have been modified when e.g. `bin/dev` isn't running.

```rb
# Under Rails 7 with 'cssbundling-rails' and/or the 'jsbundling-rails' gems,
# entirely external systems are used for asset management. With Sprockets no
# longer synchronously building assets on-demand and only when the source files
# changed, compiled assets might be (during local development) or will almost
# always be (CI systems) either out of date or missing when tests are run.
#
# People are used to "bundle exec rspec" and things working. The out-of-box gem
# 'cssbundling-rails' hooks into a vanilla Rails "prepare" task, running a full
# "css:build" task in response. This is quite slow and generates console spam
# on every test run, but points to a slightly better solution for RSpec.
#
# This class is a way of packaging that solution. The class wrapper is really
# just a namespace / container for the code.
#
# First, if you aren't already doing this, add the folllowing lines to
# "spec_helper.rb" somewhere *after* the "require 'rspec/rails'" line:
#
#     require 'rake'
#     YourAppName::Application.load_tasks
#
# ...and call MaintainTestAssets::maintain! (see that method's documentation
# for details). See also constants MaintainTestAssets::ASSET_SOURCE_FOLDERS and
# MaintainTestAssets::EXPECTED_ASSETS for things you may want to customise.
#
class MaintainTestAssets

  # All the places where you have asset files of any kind that you expect to be
  # dynamically compiled/transpiled/etc. via external tooling. The given arrays
  # are passed to "Rails.root.join..." to generate full pathnames.
  #
  # Folders are checked recursively. If any file timestamp therein is greater
  # than (newer than) any of EXPECTED_ASSETS, a rebuild is triggered.
  #
  ASSET_SOURCE_FOLDERS = [
    ['app', 'assets', 'stylesheets'],
    ['app', 'javascript'],
    ['vendor']
  ]

  # The leaf files that ASSET_SOURCE_FOLDERS will build. These are all checked
  # for in "File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'builds')". Where files are
  # written together - e.g. a ".js" and ".js.map" file - you only need to list
  # any one of the group of concurrently generated files.
  #
  # In a standard JS / CSS combination this would just be 'application.css' and
  # 'application.js', but more complex applications might have added or changed
  # entries in the "scripts" section of 'package.json'.
  #
  EXPECTED_ASSETS = %w{
    application.js
    application.css
  }

  # Call this method somewhere at test startup, e.g. in "spec_helper.rb" before
  # tests are actually run (just above "RSpec.configure..." works reasonably).
  #
  def self.maintain!
    run_build    = false
    newest_mtime = Time.now - 100.years

    # Find the newest modificaftion time across all source files of any type -
    # for simplicity, timestamps of JS vs CSS aren't considered
    #
    ASSET_SOURCE_FOLDERS.each do | relative_array |
      glob_path = Rails.root.join(*relative_array, '**', '*')

      Dir[glob_path].each do | filename |
        next if File.directory?(filename) # NOTE EARLY LOOP RESTART

        source_mtime = File.mtime(filename)
        newest_mtime = source_mtime if source_mtime > newest_mtime
      end
    end

    # Compile the built asset leaf names into full file names for convenience.
    #
    built_assets = EXPECTED_ASSETS.map do | leaf |
      Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'builds', leaf)
    end

    # If any of the source files are newer than expected built assets, or if
    # any of those assets are missing, trigger a rebuild task *and* force a new
    # timestamp on all output assets (just in case build script optimisations
    # result in a file being skipped as "already up to date", which would cause
    # the code here to otherwise keep trying to rebuild it on every run).
    #
    run_build = built_assets.any? do | filename |
      File.exist?(filename) == false || File.mtime(filename) < newest_mtime
    end

    if run_build
      Rake::Task['javascript:build'].invoke()
      Rake::Task[       'css:build'].invoke()

      built_assets.each { | filename | FileUtils.touch(filename, nocreate: true) }
    end
  end
end
```

(EDIT) As a commenter below points out, you'll need to make sure Rake tasks are loaded in your `spec_helper.rb`, e.g.:

```rb
require 'rake'
Rails.application.load_tasks
```

Comment: It works for me, but i have to add `Rails.application.load_tasks` before Rake::Task calls

Answer (score 4):

Both `jsbundling-rails` and `cssbundling-rails` append themselves into a rake task called `test:prepare`.

There are a few ways to cause `test:prepare` to run, depending on your overall build process.

1. Call it directly:

   `bundle exec rails test:prepare test`

   Or, if running rspec outside of the `rails` command:

   `bundle exec rails test:prepare && bundle exec rspec`
2. Use a test task that already calls `test:prepare`.

   Curiously, only some test tasks call (depend on) `test:prepare`, while others (including the default `test` task) don't. Example:

   `bundle exec rails test:all`
3. Make `test:prepare` a dependency on your preferred test task.

   For example, if you normally use the `spec` task by running `bundle exec rails spec`, add this to a new or existing task file (such as `lib/tasks/tests.rake`):

   `task spec: ['css:build', 'javascript:build']`

###### Background

`test:prepare` is an empty task defined by Rails. Both `cssbundling-rails` and `jsbundling-rails` add themselves as dependencies of that task.

In general, `test:prepare` is a useful place to add any kind of dependency needed to run your tests, with the caveat that only some of Rails' default test tasks depend on it. But as mentioned above, you can always call it directly or add your own dependencies.

In most cases, calling `test:prepare` is going to be equivalent to calling both `css:build` and `javascript:build`, which is why I showed `test:prepare` in most of the above examples. On occasion, other gems or your app may an extended `test:prepare` with additional commands as well, in which case those will run as well (and would likely be wanted).

Also note that `assets:precompile` also depends on `css:build` and `javascript:build`. In my experience, `test:prepare` (or `css:build` and `javascript:build` separately) runs faster than `assets:precompile`, likely because we're running a lightweight configuration of `sprockets-rails` (as opposed to `propshaft`) and `assets:precompile` runs the entire sprockets compilation process.

Comment: Yeah, so that'd be an interesting alternative task to tall in the `MaintainTestAssets` class I give as a "self-answer". You'd still want to check timestamps though, because `test:prepare` always rebuilds all assets every time, which adds an annoying overhead to test startup, especially so if all you want to do is run a specific test from e.g. a simple model spec during development.

Comment: Yes, if you frequently find yourself with modified, uncompiled assets when running local tests, checking timestamps is going to be worthwhile. I've found the standard dev-mode watchers for JS and CSS to be sufficient during development, and then use a modified `test:prepare` that only compiles if `builds/` is empty. That covers first test-run and CI, which was my only weak spot. That said, my sense is the official way is to recompile every time. PRs to jsbundling/cssbundling-rails to quit running `yarn install` every exec weren't accepted, suggesting test startup time isn't a priority.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same dilemma while using RSpec on a new Rails 7.1.2 application.

After reading the great answer written above by @tm, I ran `rails -T` looking for a similar task for RSpec and 'discovered' this one:

```bash
bin/rails spec        # Run all specs in spec directory (excluding plugin specs)
```

It also calls `test:prepare` as mentioned by @tm.

Comment: Yes, and this is OK but has the same drawbacks of _always_ compiling on each test run, which adds a lot of overhead.